# Labview - SSMS database communication... How to communicate between Labview and Microsoft SQL Server on separate devices?

Tags: sql-server, labview

I am attempting to set up a communication between Labview and Microsoft SQL Server, on two separate devices, in order to send and receive information about the database from both labview to SQL Server and SQL Server to labview. However, when I reach the "Data Link Properties" menu, I get the same "unable to log in" error upon attempting to log into the server. The server name comes up, however, an error occurs once I move on to select the database on that server. Is there any solution or tutorial to this problem that can allow me to successfully communicate back and forth from labview and smss on separate devices?

I've opened up various ports to allow a connection, even disabled the firewalls on both devices. The devices are connected via an Ethernet cable and I AM able to ping the devices to each other. However, in regards to being unable to log into the server in ssms, I have created new users, adjusted the login properties, tried changing permissions, but anything I try doesn't seem to solve my issue.

Comment: Can you connect successfully from another application on the client PC - Excel, say? (`Data > Get External Data > From Other Sources`)?

Answer (score 0):

Can't really help much without seeing the error or some of the code of what you are trying to do.

That being said, if you go to the menu and select Help>Find Examples... and search for database, you should see a bunch of different things related to database connections. You may find the Database Connection.vi one helpful.

More info on the Database Connectivity Toolkit in LabVIEW can be found [here](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/371525a.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I see there can be one of the 2 issues

1) Inbound/Outbound port rules not set, Remote connection to server is not allowed.

2) If the server has multiple instances then you need to provide full host name of the instance you are trying to connect.

*Please refer to the below link to configure firewall rules.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-2017